# Netlogo: How can I install the "initial value" of the decrement-timer with specific conditions

Tags: timer, netlogo

I would like to set a decrement-timer when the turtle reaches the end of the road (right end). (I would like to activate the decrement- timer only for the turtle that reached the left end of the road.) And keep turning the decrement-timer until the turtle dies under the specified conditions. The setting time ("A") of the decrement-timer is set separately. I made the following sample program. But the model does not work well. Because in this sample program the initial value of the decrement-timer continues to be set with every tick, if turtle is at the right end of the road. I would like to install the initial value of the decrement-timer when the turtle reaches the end of the road. Therefore, the initial value of the decrement-timer can not be install into "to setup" programming space at the beginning of the model. When I install the initial value of the decrement-timer at "to setup", the initial value of the decrement-timer will remain in the log before the turtle reaches the end of the road. I want to avoid having troublesome counting of logs.

```
let carright one-of turtles-on patch max-pxcor 0
if carright != nobody [ 
  ask carright [ set count-down A ] ;this is the problem.
  ask carright [ set speed 0 ]
  ask carright [ set count-down count-down - 1 ]
]`
```

Hi Jen B, I made the following sample code with refering your sample code and tested it. However, the decrement counter did not move. I would be happy if you give me advice.

```
let onend? one-of turtles-on patch max-pxcor 0
ask turtles-on patch max-pxcor 0 
;;In this syntax "ask turtles with onend?" I got an error so I changed it.

[ if-else count-down > 0
  [ set count-down count-down - 1 ]
  [ 
    set gamma-A precision (random-gamma (α) (β))0
    if gamma-A <= 0 [
      die
      set number-of-turtles  number-of-turtles - 1
      set number-dead number-dead + 1
    ] 
  ]
]
ask turtles-on patch max-pxcor 0
;;I got an error in this syntax "Ask turtles - on patch max - pxcor 0 with not onend?", so I changed it.

[ set count-down A ;;This worked properly. 
  set speed 0 ;;This worked properly.
  set color red ;;This worked properly.
  set onend? TRUE
]
```

Comment: I am confused about what you are trying to do. Logically, I think you want something like 'SELECT ALL turtles on a patch with px-cor = max-pxcor who have not already got a count-down value THEN set count-down to value A' and also 'SELECT ALL turtles with a count-down value THEN reduce the count-down value by 1'. What you are doing at the moment is checking if any turtles have reached the right hand side and, if so, selecting one of them to have a count-down. You don't get the other turtles reaching the end. And you restart the countdown for whichever turtle you select.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I would like to activate the decrement- timer only for the turtle that reached the left end of the road. According to your comment that the "ask carright [X X]" in the syntax is "asking [X X] for all turtles", isn't it? I did not understand the meaning of "ask carright" well. Thank you for the pointing out. So, how can I activate the decrement-timer only for the turtle that has reached the left end of the road? I would be pleased if you give me an advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am still not clear what you are trying to do, but based on the comments discussion, this might be something closer than the code you have.

```
turtles-own [onend?]    ; note that you will have to set this to false in setup

ask turtles with [onend?]
[ if-else count-down > 0
  [ set count-down count-down - 1 ]
  [ die ]
]
ask (turtles-on patch max-pxcor 0) with [not onend?]
[ set count-down A
  set speed 0
  set onend? TRUE
]
```

Comment: Thank you for the sample code. I will link the 3D image here.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQf93.png  I want to install a decrement-timer to the red turtle location of this image. (This functions as a node or a process.) In my sample code, "carright" already seems to be stored as "turtle variable" in Netlogo. (similar to "onend?" in your code) I want to make the stop motion to the red turtle by the amount of the ticking "A" by using the decrement- timer. When the decrement timer reaches 0, after that, I want to  kill the red turtle with the probability of gamma distribution.

Comment: For reference, "if carright! = Nobody [-----]", this condition is a very strong condition, so I'm stuck. Under this condition, the turtle must be the specified patch (in this case "max-pxcor 0"). Because the condition is always executed when the turtle exists on the patch "max-pxcor 0", therefore the counter does not work well. I will review again with your  sample code.

Comment: In your original code, carright is an agent-set with membership of one turtle. What I am doing is creating a variable, one copy of which is owned by each turtle. It is a flag to say 'this turtle is at the end'. In general, my advice is that you are trying to do too much at once. Make your code simply identify the turtles of interest and turn them red. Get that to work. Then do the next bit. If you do things in small steps, it forces you to get your logic correct and also allows for easier debugging.

Comment: Thank you for your advice again. I will check with the code you suggested to me again. If there is a problem, I will ask you a question here. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the question again. In your sample code, "ask turtles with onend?" this is an error with "WITH expected this input to be a TRUE/FALSE block, but got anything insted", therefor I arrange this 
 "ask turtles with [ onend? = patch max-pxcor 0 ]". And also this sample code, "ask turtles - on patch max - pxcor 0 with not onend? " this is an error with "WITH expected this input to be an agentset, but got a number insted". I have no idea today. If you have time, would you advise me? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, without a piece of code to edit, it's impossible to test. Have added some brackets etc that should fix the problem - see edits. Please make sure you also initialise the value of onend? to FALSE for all turtles when you create them too, as I put in the note.

Comment: I appreciate your advice. In initialization, I put this code "to create - car [set onend? FALSE]". Probably succeeded! Thank you very much!!! From now, I will create a place to kill turtles with gamma distribution.